# Do you have to create an exception to end a loop?

Tags: loops, python-3.x

Im currently making python3 do the same list of things over and over again to calculate how many flowers I can buy:

```
while True:
  try: 
      flowerprices=ApiGetFlowerPrices()
      if flowerprices>3:
          <CreateException>
      else: considerbuying()
Except:
  pass
```

So if the flower prices are above 3, I just start again, refreshing all the data. I don't want to consider buying if the price is above 3. 
I would like to restart the while loop, so im not after something like "break".

I guess I could try "a"+float(2) to create an exception, but what's the more elegant alternative?

Comment: replace `<CreateException>` with `break`

Comment: Wouldn't [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) be more appropriate for the process as described?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, the OP states explicitly that the loop should not be stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `break` the loop, it will stop completely. You want to use `continue` so that `ApiGetFlowerPrices()` is called again. If your `ApiGetFlowerPrices` could return an error instead of a number, your should still use a try/except.

```
while True:
  try: 
    flowerprices=ApiGetFlowerPrices()
    if flowerprices>3:
      continue # It will skip the rest of the loop and start again.

    else: considerbuying()

  Except:
    pass
```

If you don't need a try/except, consider the [answer by DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38526830/5488275).

Answer (score 1):

You need neither `break` nor the exception.
You simply want to consider buying if the price is below 3, therefore:

```
while True:
    flowerprices = ApiGetFlowerPrices()
    if flowerprices < 3:
        considerbuying()
```

**Note** that this will create an infinite loop so you will need to consider when you want to stop checking the price.

Comment: You're correct, if the Api always returns a number. If it could return an error, you should handle it correctly.

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra that's OP's job.

Comment: Yup, that's true :)